# memory leak - RaCT driver tag

Tags: memory-leak, poolmon

I'm having an issue with Nonpaged pool using 129GB of RAM on HP ProLiant DL380 Gen9 running Windows Server 2012 R2. I used Poolmon.exe to trace out that RaCT is using 127GB but I can't find any info on that RaCT Tag. I have looked through pooltag.txt file. Please let me know what is RaCT. Also, if there is any other tool to track down memory leak that would point at particular driver or kernel related libraries.

[image: Poolmon.exe]

Answer (score 0):

open cmd prompt and type `cd C:\Windows\System32\drivers`. Download strings.exe from sysinternals, copy it to Windows folder, type `strings * | findstr RaCT` or `findstr /s RaCT *` to see which driver is using this tag. Look for a driver update.